# Iframe Displaying raw pdf data results in blank pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am generating a PDF using the service DocRaptor. It returns a PDF blob from the HTML that I provide it. Example below... *(partial portion of response).*

```
%PDF-1.4
%����

1 0 obj
<
</Type /Catalog
/Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj

2 0 obj<
</Type /Pages
/Kids [3 0 R]
/Count 1>>
endobj

4 0 obj<
</Length 5 0 R
/Filter /FlateDecode>>
stream
x��VKO�0��WDj�T����UUi���"���j7 �6���;y�YA��\�ğ�y�TplsP�=�ˀ���&��Α�Ղ��?ܼEv݃�_QR�0�6(�e�� 7��2�F���*��8'b��8KV!�����ͱ�ւ������g6F��5j�^��

�he�9����7���u��!\�R�K_��O� ��ku�����M%o#�wbށ�;����7M���џ���@֨hu�F�������}]jH2JJ��)6\R(Km�.�~�uʮ��L���
```

I am then taking that response and converting it into a blob and creating an object url then creating an iframe and placing that as a source, like below.

```
var newBlob = new Blob([invoiceInformation], {type: 'application/pdf'});
const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = data;
iframe.type = 'application/pdf';
iframe.width = '100%';
iframe.height = '400px;';
$("#invoiceDisplayArea").html(iframe);
```

The problem is, the PDF is always blank. Just a blank white page. I have confirmed the PDF from Docratpor is producing content on the page by downloading it directly from their interface. What am I missing?

Comment: If the pdf ends up blank, the cause is often that you somewhere in your code treat the pdf as text data which causes the data to be interpreted according to some character encoding. As the pdf data is binary, though, chances are high that not all byte sequences therein make sense in the given character encoding and, therefore, are replaced by '�' or something similar. I.e. this *interpretation according to some character encoding* damages the pdf data. Instead always treat pdf data as binary data.

Comment: Hi, I'm a DocRaptor developer.I don't know enough about JavaScript to help with the binary encoding problem, but the way I've seen most customers handle this situation is by setting the iframe URL to a page that actually generates the PDF and then simply returns that PDF (such http://yoursite.com/makepdf.php?page=1234). Would that help, or are you converting the PDF in JavaScript too?

Comment: @jamespaden I found the async option and have successfully achieved what I was wanting using this service.